# How to express two variables in two other variables

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

If:

$A=R\cos x$ and $B=R\sin x$

Then how can I express $R$ and $x$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ in a rigorous way? Meaning that I take the domain and range in account?

I tried:
$$\cos x=\frac{A}{R}$$
$$x=\arccos\frac{A}{R}$$
Filling it in in the second equation gives:
$$B=R\sin\arccos\frac{A}{R}$$
$$B=R\sqrt{1-\frac{A^2}{R^2}}=\sqrt{R^2-A^2}$$
$$R=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$$
Furthermore:
$$\frac{B}{A}=\frac{R\sin x}{R\cos x}=\tan x$$
Therefore:
$$x=\arctan\frac{B}{A}$$
However, I feel maybe this could be done in a more simple way, and also I am not sure whether this is rigorous when it comes to range and domains. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think so

Comment: @ArchisWelankar For example: if x=arccos(A/R) indeed, then x should be between 0 and pi, while I think x could also have different values...

Comment: For any real values x we can get arccos..

Comment: You got two answers two days ago but have given no feedback at all. Is something wrong with the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem that $x$ and $R$ are not uniquely defined by $A$ and $B$. If you have a given $A$ and $B$, then for any valid $x$ and $R$ you also have

$$A=R\cos(x+2k\pi), \quad B=R\sin(x+2k\pi)$$
and
$$A=(-R)\cos(x+(2k+1)\pi), \quad B=(-R)\sin(x+(2k+1)\pi)$$
for $k\in\Bbb Z$.

So to get unique values of $x$ and $R$ you will need to set limits, such as

$$R\ge 0, \quad -\pi < x \le \pi$$

Even then, the pair $A=0,\ B=0$ will have infinitely many values of $x$. But other than that special case, with those restrictions each $A$ and $B$ will defined a unique $x$ and $R$.

Here is a simpler way to get the value of $x$. If $A\ne 0$ then $R \ne 0$, and

$$\begin{align}
\tan x &= \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \\[2ex]
 &= \frac{R\sin x}{R\cos x} \\[2ex]
 &= \frac BA
\end{align}$$

But note that this does not work for $A=0$. Also note that this does not uniquely define $x$: for any such $x$ the values $x\pm\pi$ also satisfy the equation, so you get *two* such values of $x$. If one such $x$ is in the first quadrant then another valid $x$ is in the third quadrant, and if one such $x$ is in the second quadrant then another valid $x$ is in the fourth quadrant, and vice versa.

The usual solution to those problems is to avoid the arctangent function but to rather use the [atan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). You can then uniquely define $x$ by

$$x=\operatorname{atan2}(B,A)$$

Note that some computer systems use $\operatorname{atan2}(A,B)$ instead.

You get the appropriate unique value of $R$ by

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{A^2+B^2} &= \sqrt{(R\cos x)^2 + (R\sin x)^2} \\[2ex]
 &= \sqrt{R^2(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x)} \\[2ex]
 &= \sqrt{R^2\cdot 1} \\[2ex]
 &= R
\end{align}$$

remembering that we restricted $R\ge 0$.

So the final answer is

> $$x=\operatorname{atan2}(B,A)$$
>   $$R=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$$

This gives the unique $x,R$ that satisfy $-\pi<x\le\pi,\ R\ge 0$, with the sole exception of $A=0,\ B=0$ which would allow any value of $x$. But that solution always works.

If you do not like the atan2 function, [the Wikipedia article on atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) gives some other ways to express the same result, but those other ways are much more verbose.

Comment: Thanks for your extended reply! Much appreciated. I understand and knew your answer very well. What I was looking for out of curiosity was the other more "complicated" way by taking x=arccos(A/R). Because in that way I ran into all kinds of problems with domains and ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right angle triangle with angle $x$ and hypotenuse of length 1. You will immediately see that $B^2 + A^2 = R^2$. Any number of trigonometric identities may then be used to express $x$.